# Cluster computing with java , Akka and Play 2 framewrok

Tags: java, playframework, cluster-computing, load-balancing, akka

I want to built a cluster system that will involve load balancing , parallel activities using Java with Akka and play 2 framework. 
I have read about the Akka remote clustering , and distributing task to child Actors using Akka routes. I know that Play 2 framework also implements java Akka.

Now my problem is that I want to combine java Akka and Play 2 framework to build a cluster system were I can implement load balancing and parallel execution of task.

Will be excited if someone can give me examples of such implementation or point me towards such resources or links

thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a great place to start: http://letitcrash.com/post/29044669086/balancing-workload-across-nodes-with-akka-2

Comment: thanks , will look at it and get back to you. Hav a nice time

Comment: thanks ,the link was very useful. however it is written in scala and I am not very familiar with scala is there a java version of the articles. Will be very happy for a response.